# native action bar is Not supported on my Android 4.0.x platform device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-actionbar

I am implementing **Android native action bar** in my app. On [Android developer website of native action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), it says **ActionBar APIs were added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)**.

My App target is:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

I run my app on the phone [Samsung Galaxy S2 GTI9100, Android version 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich)](http://www.androidaddicted.com/firmware/samsung/android/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-gt-i9100-i9100xwlp2-ice-cream-sandwich-ics-4-0-3-russia-firmware-update-518.html) , the **overflow** part(right-most drop down menu) of **native action bar** however is not showing, instead it use the physical touch button to show the menu.

Why? I am testing my app on Android 4.0.3 platform, why native action bar is not working? though the android developer website said it is added in Android 3.0 (API level 11)... **and how to make it working?(display 'overflow' drop down menu on actoin bar instead of physical menu button)**

Answer (score 0):

Change your targetSdkVersion to 14

Comment: But my app need to target to 13, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add HOLO theme to your activity or application if android version is 11 or greater. For example

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
       setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
}
```